# Mulimeter Ripple Current Error

Tags: power-supply, multimeter

I have two multimeters. One is very good, the other one is quite cheap. I am measuring a regulated power supply to see if it is in indeed regulated. Both so 5.4 V, unloaded and loaded. This seems to indicate that it is in fact regulated.

When I measure AC voltage, the cheap multimetre shows 10 V, and the good multimetre shows 60 mV. I assume the cheap multimeter value is incorrect. Do you have any idea why this would occur?

Also, I am using this power supply for powering an Arduino 5V, supplying voltage at the 5V pin. It seems to work just fine. Do you think the extra 0.4 V will cause problems over the long run?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Fed, we don't know what type of meters you have. Digital, analogue, etc. You haven't provided model numbers or links to datasheets, etc. Even a photo ...

Comment: Does your cheap multimeter properly measure AC voltages that have no DC offset? Test it with sine-wave input. Also test it with square wave input.

Comment: There has been some previous discussion of certain cheap DVMs that, when measuring a DC voltage but set to AC, will display something significantly higher than the DC voltage. (I vaguely recollect a model number like UT-33).

Comment: The cheap meter is labeled XL830L.  Otherwise it seems to work well.  So, any idea why that would happen?  I am just curious.  Also, would 5.4V on the Arduino 5V pin be ok, or should I reduce the voltage somehow?